# Как задать ::after после div в виде картинки?

Tags: html, css

Хочу добавить после каждого div, за исключением первого, стрелочку, но почему-то она не появляется. Что я делаю не так?

```css
.steps-block {
  display: flex;
}

.steps-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffd200;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.steps-img::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("../img/steps/arrow_curved.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-block">
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/woman-with-headset.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/clock.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/money.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/folded-document.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/calendar.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

И как дополнительный вопрос: как добавить этот ::after ко всем div, кроме первого?

Comment: Где стрелочка? Где пример конечного результата? Хоть на листочке нарисуйте, да сфотографируйте.

Comment: Дело в том, что `::after` не имеет размеров, вы их просто не указали, `img` выставляет размер своего блока из размера изображения, а любой элемент с `background-image` так не умеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментариях, у вас не указан размер `::after`.

```
.steps-img::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  background: url("../img/steps/arrow_curved.png");
}
```

---

> И как дополнительный вопрос: как добавить этот ::after ко всем div, кроме первого?

Есть такой классный рецепт [`:not(:first-child)`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_not) (все, кроме первого элемента).

```css
.steps-block {
  display: flex;
}

.steps-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffd200;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.steps-img:not(:first-child)::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/arrow.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-block">
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/woman-with-headset.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/clock.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/money.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/folded-document.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/calendar.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

---

Ну или `::first-child` (первый элемент) и `display: none;`

```css
.steps-block {
  display: flex;
}

.steps-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffd200;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.steps-img::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/arrow.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
}

.steps-img:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-block">
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/woman-with-headset.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/clock.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/money.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/folded-document.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="steps-img"><img src="img/steps/calendar.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```